# Differences between TM and GDT-TS scores for structure comparison

Tags: protein-structure, statistics, modelling

What are the relative advantages / disadvantages of the TM (template modelling) and GDT (global distance test, total score) scores, used in protein structure prediction competitions, such as [CASP](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwir2PqO1-XVAhVHPhQKHcFGBF0QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCASP&usg=AFQjCNENea3DBFw-bFeW2BRImlsjhtnxDA)? When should I choose one over the other?

Comment: Hi. This question seems to need more information to get a good answer as it looks (to me) too general. Could you please [edit] adding what have you found/read about each tool, or any paper you read on the topic to help me answer you?